# Magento XMLConnect...what is it and how can I use it?

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

Can someone explain what the XMLConnect extension is and what it is used for?  I know that in general it can be used to develop a mobile friendly site, but that's about as far as I've gotten with my Google searches.  Does anyone have experience working with this extension and can provide some details and/or examples?

Thanks!

Comment: This type of question doesn't really belong on Stack Overflow, as it's not a programming question. You should take a look at http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/25439/magento and see about getting a proper place to put these kind of questions

Comment: Can a moderator move this to magento.stackechange.com? I think it would certainly be an appropriate question there.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

XMLConnect is, essentially, an XML service.  One way to think of a "normal" Magento website is

- Backend code adds things to carts, fetches products from database, etc.
- Execution is handed off to the layout system
- Layout system makes HTML/Javascript/CSS

Magento has a product called Magento Mobile, which lets you create an iPhone or Android application to sell products from your Magento system.  Magento Mobile works something like this

- Backend code add things to carts, fetches products from databases, etc.
- Execution is handed off to an XML rendering system
- XML is sent back to the phone
- The binary application sitting on the phone processes the XML and makes the pixels on the phone look and act like a store

XMLConnect is the module that lets Magento do this.  It creates XML requests/responses.

Additional Reading: [Develop your own Magento mobile application](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/develop-your-own-magento-mobile-application/)

Comment: Thanks Alan!  As always, very helpful!

Comment: With latest version and RWD theme seems like this is deprecated.